# How to use @Template and cache at the same time?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Is there a way to modify the $response to set the cache, and still return an array? (I don't want to use the template name and render)

I'm only able to do that with the @Cache annotation, but sure there must be another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate with response object using [Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#handling-requests).

For example, handling kernel.response events gives you the possibility of setting cache headers after view is rendered.